# Xcode 4.4 & 4.5 freezing on project close

Tags: xcode, xcode4, freeze, xcode4.5, xcode4.4

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 4.4 and again upgrading to 4.5 (running on Lion), Xcode appears to freeze for about 3-5 minutes every time I close my app project or quit. During this time, activity monitor shows that the CPU is pegged at 95%, although little disk activity is occurring.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Xcode and this didn't make a difference.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any suggestions what I could do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Honestly, Xcode has been incredibly buggy for me as well. It crashes and freezes all the time when I'm working on my project.

I don't know specifically what's happening but maybe its creating a snapshot or something before it exits?

Comment: Same here, I'm on Mountain Lion and have more or less the same problem. XCode hangs frequently after quitting the simulator with cmd+q.

Comment: This is pretty much every day of Xcode with me as well

Comment: is your project hooked up to any source code repository (svn, git, etc.) and does the MacOS Console.app (found in the "`/Applications/Utilities/`" folder) give any useful hints as to what might be going on while Xcode takes forever to quit?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4160869?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue, even tho the author in this discussion doesn't appear to be seeing it anymore.