# Xcode 4.4 Mountain Lion constantly hangs

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, freeze

Since installing Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 I constantly have to force quit Xcode after a debug session. I get the following error in the console "Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination." and then I can't start a new session with Xcode. I can't even close the application - the only chance is to kill it.

Here's another explination of the problem: http://www.1771.in/iphone-xcode-4-4-terminating-in-response-to-springboards-termination.html

Does someone know a workaround or bugfix for this?

Thx in Advance

Steve

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817771/xcode-4-4-freezing-on-project-close#comment15710200_11817771

Comment: Xcode 4.4.1 has just been released. You may want to check it out.